# Read the contents of the “dictionary.txt” and add all four letter words to an ADT ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

Tags: java

```
  import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class BuildGraph {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            Scanner sc=new Scanner((new File("dictionary.txt")));
            ArrayList<String> words=new ArrayList<String>();

            while(sc.hasNextLine()){
                if(sc.next().length()==4){
                words.add(sc.next());
                //sc.next();
                }
                System.out.println(words);
            }
           // sc.close();

            for (int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(words.get(i));
            }

        }
    }
```

**This is my code, and I am trying to read only 4 letter words from a dictionary file, but when i run my code it gives me all the words from dictionary files
Thank-you in advance.**

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: how to read 4 letter words from a dictionary file

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error? Not desired output? Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: it works, but doesnt give me the answer i want. I prints out all the words in a dictionary not the 4 letter ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code needs some tweaks. Basically you should not be calling sc.next() twice to get the same element as calling next() moves the pointer to the next element

Rewrite your while loop to this:

```
while(sc.hasNextLine() && sc.hasNext()){
    String word = sc.next();
    if(word.length()==4){
        words.add(word);  
    }
    System.out.println(words);
}
```